# loop through text file for first number on each line

Tags: php

the code below works for the first word on each line, but how do I get the first number on each line?  please keep in mind that the number can be 1 digit or it can be 20 digits long

```
<?php
    $file = new SplFileObject("/tmp/test.txt", "r");
    $data = array();
    while(! $file->eof()) {
         $data[] = array_shift(($file->fgetcsv("|")));
    }
    echo implode(",", $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the first number in a string:

```
function getFirstNumber($str){
    $strlen = strlen( $str );
    $num = "";
    for( $i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++ ) {
        $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
        if(!is_numeric( $char)){
            if(!empty($num))
                return intval($num);
        }else $num .= $char;
    }
    return intval($num);
}

$str = "asdfas1234241234lkj 1l2k3j4  1k2j3412341234";
echo getFirstNumber($str);
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://3v4l.org/r5fFl)

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented, gets the first part, not the first word.
You have to walk through the array using foreach, array_walk, ...

For example:

```
<?php
$file = new SplFileObject("/tmp/test.txt", "r");
$data = array();
while(! $file->eof()) {
  foreach($file->fgetcsv("|") as $part)  {
    if (is_numeric($part))  { //or any other numeric check you like
      $data[] = $part;
      break;
    }
  }
}
echo implode(",", $data);
?>
```

Comment: getting an error: syntax error unexpected end of file

Comment: Forgot a }. Solved @SlopTonio